# image cache presets in drupal 7?

Tags: image, view, drupal-7, preset

Im using drupal-7 for my new project. Since imagecache is moved to drupal core in d7. So I have created 2 image presets.Now im not able to find the image cache presets images. I want to show these images using views. But where are the image presets stored in d7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the folders in drupal install I found the images. So the preset folders are in sites/default/files/styles foler. Here it contains folder for all the presets created with imagecache.